# WHMCS - how to get product group (gid) in product detais

Tags: whmcs

I'm designing a whmcs theme, I'm trying to filter my products by its Group id (gid) in product details page in clientarea.
but i can not use this ex:

```
{if $gid eq "1"}
```

does any one knows how can i get product group id  in clientarea product details page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view available smarty variables, you add `{debug}` to the end of the tpl file. A pop up window will show all variables as key: value.

In your case add it to `clientareaproductdetails.tpl`

The variable you're looking for is 'pid'. and your code becomes:

```
{if $pid eq "1"}
```